# How to get query transaction id from AWS managed blockchain using chaincode

Tags: blockchain, chaincode, amazon-managed-blockchain

I am not able to get transaction id from AWS managed blockchain using chaincode's **stub.getState(key)** method. Please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

Please try the stub method `getTxID()` instead.

Or, you can get it from the transaction object at the client layer when submitting the transaction